# How to assign a role/permissions to a service account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am running a terraform script to automate the folder creation in GCP under Organization. I am using a service account to execute the terraform script. While running terraform apply, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Error creating folder 'prod' in 'organizations/xxxxxxxxxx': googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
    "method": "google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.Folders.CreateFolder",
    "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
  }
]

More details: 
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
  on main.tf line 10, in resource "google_folder" "prod":
  10: resource "google_folder" "prod" {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDuns.png)

I am seeking assistance to know how could I apply CreateFolder permission to my service account in GCP. Screenshot of the error message is also attached as a link in this post.

Thank You.

Comment: Go to your folder, to IAM page and add the permission to your service account email.

Comment: Where are you running terraform at (Compute Engine, local desktop, etc)? Do not post just an error message, include the HCL also.

Comment: This doc [1] might help this question.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-folders